# Binary search function versus .index() efficiency in Python

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I wrote a binary search that returns the index of a given item in a sorted list:

```
def fn(data, item):
    n = len(data)
    left = 0
    right = n -1

    while left <= right:
        middle = (left+right) // 2
        if item < data[middle]:
            right = middle -1
        elif item > data[middle]:
            left = middle +1
        else:
            return middle
    raise ValueError('Value is not in the list')
```

My data is the following:

```
data = [x**2 for x in range(10000)]
```

I check how much time it takes to find  the index of `876**2`:

```
%%timeit
fn(data, 767376)
# 2.48 µs ± 59.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

And the built-in `list.index()` method:

```
%%timeit
data.index(767376)
# 9.93 µs ± 98.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Then I played around finding different numbers trying to find out where the times meet:

```
%%timeit
fn(data, 22500)
# 1.77 µs ± 43.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
data.index(22500)
# 1.79 µs ± 41.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

I am wondering at what number of items or what kind of other factors there are which would answer my question, when should I use `list.index()` and my own defined function that returns the index of a selected element.

I tried finding how the `list.index()` is constructed in CPython but with no success.

To sum up, what kind of search does the built-in `list.index()` method uses and when is it more efficient to use versus my own declared binary search?

Comment: Python doesn't _know_ the list is sorted when you call `.index()` on it. Internally, I'm 90% sure it uses the 'iterate through one item at a time' to search for things. If this matters to you, have you considered using a `dict` to store the data instead of a `list`, which is much faster for trying to find a particular element? e.g. `dct = {e:i for i,e in enumerate(sorted(data))}`

Comment: Standart library contains [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html). It is better to compare with it. There is also a section "Searching Sorted Lists"

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Could you point me to the right direction to answer my, then, next question: why searches in dicts are faster than lists in terms of how their search algorithms are written?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table for the usual algorithm.  Short version, you map keys to buckets using a hash function, then search the bucket.  Even if a lot of things are in the hash, very few will be in the bucket.  So the cost is constant, no matter the overall size.